# Could you suggest software to draw a cross section, companion to QGIS?

Tags: qgis, cad, cross-section

If you use GIS systems, what software do you turn to when there is a requirement to draw a cross section?

Ideally a workflow that includes QGIS. Typically there are some points which will coexist in the plan and section view. But often I find there is much more detail to be input in the section which is redundant to have in x y coordinate system.

Related to this question
[Drawing cross section in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/30018/how-to-draw-a-cross-section-in-qgis)

but what is your experience?  Perhaps you do street plans and need to represent the road and verge profile from time to time.

Not Arc addons please.

Comment: Hi @Willy. How is this question different from your previous one? To me it seems that the answers would be same.

Comment: Thanks A, the previous question for solutions within QGIS. I am now interested in workflows which might take the same data and use it in other systems.

Answer (score 2):

So I am looking at SketchUp with a ruby script, Cloud.

http://rld.crai.archi.fr/rld/plugin_details.php?id=777

This plugin allows the import of csv files, but with crude labelling.

The CAD programs, DoubleCAD XT and flavours of IntelliCAD cost money to have the functionality to import csv, typically the workflow is to create a terrain, apparently.

Comment: Well I am hoping for something better, but would like to put something here for any other enquirers