# Drawing archaeological sections in QGIS

Tags: qgis, archaeology

I'm trying to figure out a way to draw archeological sections in QGIS ([example](http://provincielimburg.adlibsoft.com/wwwopacx/wwwopac.ashx?command=getcontent&server=images&value=4029%20Kerkrade%20Holzkuil/4029%20Kerkrade-Holzkuil-tek.nr.%20184-PRO.jpg&width=580&height=580)). We currently only draw the layers and features digitally ([like this](http://docplayer.nl/docs-images/56/39762349/images/30-0.jpg)). When we make a section of features or a profile we draw a line from point a to b with the gps and make an analog drawing of the actual section or profile.

The idea is to draw section in the field on a rugged tablet within QGIS and link them to a section line (point a to b).

How do I set this up?

Comment: So you're just looking to take data you already have and create cross sectional profiles from it? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Sorry it took a while for me to respond, i was in the field. What i've seen another company do is plot a millimeter grid in qgis and draw a profile on that. Later they would link it to the a-b line measured with the gps so you'd have a spatial link. I'm fairly inexperienced in Qgis and i'm learning by figuring stuff out myself but i can't find info on how to approach this problem.

Comment: Take a look at [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/30018/113585). Does it help you any? If you have known elevation values for the a-b line or a reasonably hi-res DEM of the area, you can create the profile line digitally within QGIS, instead of drawing by hand.

Comment: profileAAR Plugin?
https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/profileAAR/